# C struct initialization number of array elements initialized at compile time

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compilation

```
typedef struct
{
  struct item_t items[MAX_ITEMS];
  int num_items;
} item_list_t;`

items_list_t item_list = 
{
    .items = 
    {
#ifdef ITEM1
      {
           /* item1 initialized here */
      },
#endif
#ifdef ITEM2
      {
           /* item2 initialized here */
      },
#endif
#ifdef ITEM3
      {
           /* item3 initialized here */
      },
#endif
    }
    /* Find out how many items were initialized */
    .num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(struct item_t); //doesn't work
}
```

I am trying to find a way to populate the .num_items field with the number of items in the array that were initialized at **compile** time. I know why the code example doesn't work, im wondering if there is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Why not just `#if defined(ITEM1) && !defined(ITEM2) && !defined(ITEM3)` then `.num_items = 1` etc.

Comment: The array is always MAX_ITEMS in size but I want to be able to determine how many were initialized with values.

Comment: @KamilCuk that could require a lot of cases depending on how many ITEM's there are.

Comment: Yes. That's why many C projects use for example `m4` or other scripts to generate source files. You could also use `__COUNTER__` or boost counter - increment in each `#ifdef` and then just `.num_items = __COUNTER__`

Answer (score 0):

A not portable hack would be to use the `__COUNTER__` preprocessor extension. It's not a standard C feature, but should be supported in recent gcc, clang and msvc compilers.

The preprocessor increments the value of the counter after each *evaluation*, so you have to force evaluation using something like:

```
// in case __COUNTER__ was previously used in a different header
const static int initial_counter = __COUNTER__; 

#ifdef ITEM1 
  const static int item1_defined = __COUNTER__; // +1
#endif
#ifdef ITEM2
  const static int item2_defined = __COUNTER__; // +1
#endif
#ifdef ITEM3
  const static int item3_defined = __COUNTER__; // +1
#endif

// must subtract 1 because this line also evaluates __COUNTER__
const static int total_item_count = (__COUNTER__) - initial_counter - 1;
```

And then:

```
items_list_t item_list = 
{
    .items = { ... },
    .num_items = total_item_count
}
```

A more portable preprocessor alternative is to use [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/headers/slot/counter.html) which should be more portable (but it's written for C++ so you might have to port some of the details to C yourself), or use a code generator (recommended).

Involving a code generator into your build scripts will generate actual source code you can step in and debug if needed. Preprocessor hacks can easily get out of hand.